# How to add Meta Tag just below title tag programmaticallyin c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to programmatically add a `<meta>`. It is working fine but problem is that it is not adding the tag just below title tag in header section of the page:

```
Page.Title = "TestPage";
HtmlMeta redirectMetaTag = new HtmlMeta ();
redirectMetaTag.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
redirectMetaTag.Content = "IE=9";
this.AbcHead.Controls.Add(redirectMetaTag);
```

In my ASPX page there is JavaScript just below empty title tag in header section, so whenever I am trying to add above code on Page_Load(), the meta tag always comes after JavaScript tag. So can anyone suggest how to add meta tag just below title tag?

Comment: Is this asp.net?  or mvc?  or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If this is ASP.NET WebForms, which looks like it might be, you can add a [PlaceHolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) control to your form anywhere you please, like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="phMetaTag" runat="server" />
```

Then just do this:

```
Page.Title = "TestPage";
HtmlMeta redirectMetaTag = new HtmlMeta ();
redirectMetaTag.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
redirectMetaTag.Content = "IE=9";
phMetaTag.Controls.Add(redirectMetaTag);
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging into this I got the answer:

```
phMetaTag.Controls.AddAt(1, redirectMetaTag);
```

This will place my meta tag just after title tag.